# SSL DNS entries for CloudBees

Tags: cloudbees

I see that we need to setup our DNS to point to our new router with SSL configured. My question is can we just use the CloudBees DNS entries if we don't have our own domain name? I.e. is there a way to point myapp.mycompany.cloudbees.net to the router with my SSL cert setup on that? Or do I have to go purchase a domain name from a 3rd party provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will have to purchase a certificate for your router/IP service.

We are looking into a shared SSL service for this (which will probably do what you want) - this requires a flattening of names, however, as SSL certs aren't issued with 2 levels of "wild cards" at this time.